# FacebookCallback<LoginResult> doesn't execute all the code -android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x

//code

```
      callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        Profile profile;
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
             profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                            // Application code
                            try {
                                email=object.getString("email");
                                login(email,profile.getId());

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

            nextActivity();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        }
    };
public void login(String email,String password){
    editor.putBoolean("islogin",true);
    editor.putString("email", email);
    editor.putString("password",password);
    editor.commit();
}
```

I want to get email from FacebookCallback but the login method doesn't execute and when I try  to use email(variable) out of the callback I get the  first value of email??  how can I solve this problem !! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the `email` variable wasn't in the code snippet it must have come from outside of the nested anonymous functions: `new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()` and `new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()` Which means it would have had to been declared `final` and so the value couldn't have been reset in your code: `email=object.getString("email");`

You should use a local variable instead:

```
try {
  String userEmail =object.getString("email");
  login(userEmail,profile.getId());
}
```

Comment: thanks brow but also it doesn't work 
I try :
int id =0 // in onCreate method 

try {
  email =object.getString("email");
  Log.v("Email",email);
  Log.v("Email",""+id);
}
but in log cat I get only the email I think that only one instruction is execute

Comment: Did you create new local String variable too? Maybe post more code including your update so I can get a better idea of what's going on?